# How to configure lighttpd display custom 500 error page?

Tags: linux, lighttpd

When my php works not correctly, server sends 500 error to browser by default. I want to see my custom error page. I tried to use servererror-file prefix, but not work with 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

In lighttpd 1.4.46 (not yet released), you can choose to intercept errors from dynamic handlers using `server.error-intercept = "enable"`.  See https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/974

However, a better solution is to trap the errors in your PHP script and issue an appropriate error page, rather than crashing.